# How to detect when user changes keyboards?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard, emoji

Is there some way to detect when the user changes keyboard types, specifically to the Emoji keyboard in this case?

Comment: What is the problem you need to solve?

Comment: @Zaph I'm trying to present a new UIView on screen when the Emoji keyboard is shown.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `UITextInputMode` to detect the current language of the `currentInputMode` -- emoji is considered a language. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputMode_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> An instance of the `UITextInputMode` class represents the current
>   text-input mode. You can use this object to determine the primary
>   language currently being used for text input.

You can test for the emoji keyboard like this:

```
NSString *language = [[UITextInputMode currentInputMode] primaryLanguage];
BOOL isEmoji = [language isEqualToString:@"emoji"];
if (isEmoji)
{
   // do something
}
```

You can be notified of the input mode changing via the `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification`. This will post when the current input mode changes.

Here's a simple app which prints an `NSLog` whenever the mode changes:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(changeInputMode:) 
             name:UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification object:nil];}
}

-(void)changeInputMode:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSString *inputMethod = [[UITextInputMode currentInputMode] primaryLanguage];
    NSLog(@"inputMethod=%@",inputMethod);
}
```

Or if you prefer [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-XID_1):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController 
{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, 
       selector: "changeInputMode:", 
           name: UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func changeInputMode(notification : NSNotification)
    {
        let inputMethod = UITextInputMode.currentInputMode().primaryLanguage
        println("inputMethod: \(inputMethod)")
    }


}
```

Comment: @MichaelGEmmons currentInputMode is deprecated in iOS7. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @Apollo Yep. The new method is `activeInputModes` which returns an array of UITextInputMode objects. Check that array for an inputMode with the `primaryLanguage` of _emoji_ and you'll get the same results.

Comment: @MichaelGEmmons that array returns all of the users possible keyboards in constant order. How would I know which keyboard we're on?

Comment: The notification object is the current input mode. Get the primary language from that.

Comment: And this works too:  myTextView.textInputMode.primaryLanguage;

Comment: Note: this does not work for the ABC/123 button. Still looking for a way to check that.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
     selector: #selector(FirstViewController.changeInputMode(_:)),
     name: NSNotification.Name.UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChange, object: nil)

func changeInputMode(_ notification: Notification) 
    {
        let inputMethod = UITextInputMode.activeInputModes.description
        print("keyboard changed to \(inputMethod.description)")
    }
```