# UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is called when keyboard is switched to emoji

Tags: ios, keyboard

I currently have the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification setup with my keyboard. When i tap the keyboard's emoji button, the notification is called, drastically messing up my UI (for i have a tool bar with a text field "attached" to it). I assume this is suppose to happen, but is there a way to detect if the keyboard is simply switching the type of keyboard? I would like that notification to be called only when the keyboard actually closes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167856/how-to-detect-when-user-changes-keyboards)

Notice that after iOS7, Apple suggest use textInputMode.primaryLanguage, but the emoji keyboard will return nil when you access the primaryLanguage. Seem like it's a bug.